# Reasons for a HTTP 503 Service unavailable Error

Tags: java, web-services, http, soap, soapui

At work i have to implement an EDI thing. I have to create an XML message, sign it with a certificate, encode it with `Base64`, pack it in an XML structure and send it to a server.
To send the message to the soap service i use [HTTPSOAPConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/xml/internal/messaging/saaj/client/p2p/HttpSOAPConnection.java). The problem i ran into is, that i always get a `503 service unavailable` error.
I thought okay the service is not started, but for curiosity i tryed to reach it with `SoapUi`. Sending the same message to the same service endpoint i get a `HTTP 200 Ok`, with a response message.
Analyzing this response i have found, that there is a `Base64` encoed xml inside, like the service documentation said. Decoding this i found out, that the server sent me an error code, saying that the service is unavailable.
But how can it be, that with my java generated request i get a 503 and with SoapUi i get a service specific response, containing the service specific error code for 503?
The only thing i can think about is, that something is wrong with my request. But what other reasons can a Http 503 have? How can i analyze the error (for example comparing the `MimeHeader` of SoapUi with mine...)?
One more information i can give you is the block in which the error occures: Starting at line 245 of [HTTPSOAPConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/xml/internal/messaging/saaj/client/p2p/HttpSOAPConnection.java)

```
responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
// let HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR (500) through because it is used for SOAP faults
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR) {
    isFailure = true;
}
//else if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
//else if (!(responseCode >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK && responseCode < 207))
else if ((responseCode / 100) != 2) {
    log.log(Level.SEVERE,
    "SAAJ0008.p2p.bad.response",
    new String[] {httpConnection.getResponseMessage()});
    throw new SOAPExceptionImpl(
        "Bad response: ("
        + responseCode
        + httpConnection.getResponseMessage()
    );
}
```

I am getting this "Bad response", with a 503 response code and no response message.
I hope this informations are enough to, at least, get some guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, like i get this, cause of a wrong endpoint URL. The URL i use as an endpoint is actually the URL to the WSDL. The endpoint itself is another one.
I stil did not get it to work, but thats cause of some SSL, certificate, keystore, etc. stuff, which i have to learn first :P And it seems complicated...